# C: lists, structures: error: structure has no member

Tags: c, file, list, structure, member

English is not my motherlanguage, I'm sorry for any grammar mistakes in the description or in the code, I translated it in order to share it here with you.

Hello, I'm writing a little program in C and I need some help, I'm stuck with one error I can't fix, I searched here on forums and anywhere else, but nothing I found helped me. The other functions in the program work just fine.

This function reads a list of words and categories from txt file, puts it into a structure, makes a list. The user types what word he wants to delete from file, so function searches if it's there and deletes if it is.

I'm not the best with lists so there's probably a really basic, stupid problem here, any help please?

```
void REMOVE_WORD (int howmanylines)
{

 FILE *fp;

if ((fp=fopen("words.txt", "r+w"))==NULL)              
    {printf("Error while opening the file!\n");
    exit(1);}
else
{
typedef struct base                                      
    {
        struct base *next;
        char word[25];
        char category[15];
    } list_els;

    struct base tab[howmanylines];
    int i=0;                                        
    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", &tab[i].word);
        fscanf(fp, "%s", &tab[i].category);
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    list_els *head;
    list_els *el=(list_els*)malloc(sizeof(list_els));
    list_els *ind=head;
    while (ind->next)
    {
        ind=ind->next;
        ind->next=el;
    }



    printf("What word do you want to remove?\n\n");
    char word_remove[25];
    scanf("%s", &word_remove);
    if (strcmp(ind->next->word, word_remove)==0)
    {
        printf("Found:\n Word: | Category:\n %s | %s\n", ind->next->word, ind->next->category);
        printf("Are you sure you want to remove?\n1)Yes\n 2)No\n\n");
        int removing;
        if (removing==1)
        {
            list_els *removed=ind->next;
            ind->next=removed->next;
            free(removed);
        }
        else if (removing==2) {printf("Removing cancelled.\n\n");}
        else {printf("Wrong operation number!");}
    }
    else printf("Word not available in the base!\n\n");
    }
```

}

It shows me an error 'struct base' has no member named 'word' in the line where I use the strcmp.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce that error: http://ideone.com/CnCz1S

Comment: Do you really think the most appropriate place to define your structure with a `typedef` is inside an `else`? Bye bye code readability...

Comment: If you do get this code to compile, it is going to fail spectacularly.  Lets start with the basics:  you read the entire file into an array `struct base tab[]`, and then you try turn it into a list, but only allocate one record, and use use the value `ind->next` before its even set, and then you only test one pointer to see if it matches `word_remove`.  You may be reaching a little too high.

Comment: Variable length arrays aren't supported in older versions of c, so you won't be able to define `tab[howmanylines]`. Which version are you using? did you compile with `-std=c99`?

Comment: As said, I'm still a beginner when working with lists and I'm looking for any tips and clues. As told, I knew there will be really basic mistakes. Thank you for pointing them out, I'll be working on lists way more, but can you tell me how to actually solve this one problem please?

Comment: it's the process does not make sense as a whole. It's a good idea to have to the processing of only delete the word that you specify in this function by creating a word book in the main.

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet

> ```
> list_els *head;
> list_els *el=(list_els*)malloc(sizeof(list_els));
> list_els *ind=head;
> while (ind->next)
> {
>     ind=ind->next;
>     ind->next=el;
> }
> ```

You are not initialising `ind` to any valid value. You probably meant to write `ind = el` instead of `head`. Also, don't cast `malloc()`.